# Find the number of times a tweet has been viewed

Tags: twitter

There have been quite a few number of start-up pertaining to analyzing Twitter data. There is [CrowdBooster](http://crowdbooster.com/), then there is [Klout](http://klout.com/), which use Twitter data to tell the user their True reach.

I have got the following two questions:

1) Is there a way to find out who has viewed one's tweet, or the number of people that have viewed a tweet. Crowdbooster claims to tell you how many impression one received per tweet. How do they do it?

2) Thousands and thousands of links are shared each day on Twitter. Can we find out which user has clicked the link in a tweet?

I have looked through Twitter API and some of the companies that have licensed Twitter's Firehose, but have not found anything that meet my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, to give you a short answer to your 2nd question. Now that we've established that view analysis is impossible. Can you find out which user has clicked on that link, absolutely. And depending on what your talking about, user as far as the user who has clicked on the link or the user that has the link on their Twitter stream. Both are possible,

in the case of A, you would get the referring users IP address. Methods vary depending on language.

But what I think your asking for is scenario B, finding out which user has the link in their Twitter stream. This can be done by querying the link, the API response you will get can include tweet entities which will list all this information out for you and more. Open up a firehose with your link and watch what comes in.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is there a way to find out who has viewed one's tweet, or the
>   number of people that have viewed a tweet. Crowdbooster claims to tell
>   you how many impression one received per tweet. How do they do it?

No, in the case of a view - this would be impossible. The tweet impression can happen in multiple silos. On the website, in a widget, in a mobile app. You can imagine that it's simply not possible to get the impression of a tweet on a view because of this reason and because unlike a click, there is no I viewed this tweet identifier sent when a view has been enacted. I spent a great deal of time researching for a way to get the tweet impression even based on a similar clicked link and this is not even possible. *(edit: it's possible see the last paragraph)* This brings us to question 2.

> 2) Thousands and thousands of links are shared each day on Twitter.
>   Can we find out which user has clicked the link in a tweet?

Yes, what these websites are mainly doing is analyzing links that you process through their website. If you can have a unique hash marker on a link then analysis becomes possible. Without a unique hash marker, Twitter will re-interrupt two of the same links in a exactly the same way, even in the case that it shortens your link to it's custom `t.co` wrapper.

This means the only reliable way to do tweet analysis is by including a unique link marker code on your tweet and analyze the the fact that somebody that has hit your server has clicked on that link.

There is a somewhat hidden Twitter API feature that helps you understand how popular a particular link is. That being the link count API .. http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=

Something really outside of the box you can do if your set on analyzing multiple versions of exactly the same link without using markers and if your also using the Streaming (firehose) would be to analyze the tweet views (using the link count API) on similar links that hit your server. The link that got the +1 boost in view is the one that hit your server. But that's about the extent of creative analysis you can get with your tweets and more specifically the links, as mentioned links are the only thing your really able to analyze when it comes to Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is there a way to find out who has viewed one's tweet, or the number of people that have viewed a tweet. Crowdbooster claims to tell you how many impression one received per tweet. How do they do it?

Yes, sign up for Twitter Analytics https://analytics.twitter.com (free service provided by Twitter) and you can see how many people view (impressions) for each tweet and totals for specific dates or a date range.

> 2) Thousands and thousands of links are shared each day on Twitter. Can we find out which user has clicked the link in a tweet?

Yes, you can do this. Using a URL shortening service like Bitly.com you can track how many clicks you had from Twitter (only give out that Bitly link on Twitter to do this). But if you want more indept information you may need to create a tracking software, as I don't know of any available. To do that you would need the tracking software to track the link and find out the refer header and see if it's from Twitter (or better yet, just give out a unique URL for your tweets), then you would need to use the Twitter API to find out the handle (username) of that visitor who clicked your link. Lastly store this information in a database so you can review who clicked what link.